# How to creat a scatterplot to vizualize the relationships between two waves of a study in R?

Tags: r, plot, filter

I've been having trouble creating a scatterplot in R to compare waves 1 and 2 of the following study

```
gay <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/umbertomig/intro-prob-stat-FGV/master/datasets/gay.csv")
```

I have tried using the following codes but no alterations I could figure on my own seem to work

```
wave1 <- filter(gay, gay$wave == 1)
wave2 <- filter(gay, gay$wave == 2)

pairs(gay, pch = 19)

pairs(wave1, pch = 19)

pairs(wave2, pch = 19)

plot(gay$ssm, gay$wave, pch = 19)
plot(wave1, gay$ssm, pch = 19)
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: None of these codes actually have problems to them, but they don't provide useful results either. This problem asks specifically for a scatterplot, comparing the results of the first wave of study to the results to the second. I think it wants me to plot a scatter between `~ssm` and `~treatment` (being `~treatment` a variable with 3 possible results) but I could be completely wrong on this one.
Thank you all in advance for the insights on this question so far, they have been useful!

In case it helps, the full question for this problem is

```
 ## Most surveys find at least some outliers or individuals whose responses are substantially different from the rest of the data. In addition, some respondents may change their responses erratically over time. Create a scatter plot to visualize the relationships between wave 1 and each of the subsequent waves in study 2. Use only the control group. Interpret the results.
```

Comment: Not clear what your asking, but why not use two different colors to display two different data sets? Also -- `plot()` creates a new plot but `points()` adds more points to an existing plot. Do the first dataset with `plot()` and then add the second with `points()`  (there are other ways of doing this, but this is straightforward).

Comment: Not knowing what you're going after, I might start with `xtabs(~ wave + ssm + study, data = gay)` (non-graphical). Because your 69K of observations are mostly categorical (2 studies, 5 treatments, 7 waves, and 5 `ssm`s), pairs and scatters will be less helpful.

Comment: Having said that, your question is a bit vague: while none of those commands *fails*, it does not seem that you have a programming problem, more of an analysis problem. SO does occasionally field questions like that, but it might be more appropriate on [stats.se] or [datascience.se]. If you are seeing errors or plotting *problems*, though, then you will need to [edit] your question and include specific information and reproducible problems.

Comment: It would help if you could set out what you want to plot in principle. Maybe give an example of your expected output or the graph you expect to produce?